# How to have a clean install of a flutter package after previously making an edit to the package?

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-pub

I installed a flutter package, played around with the package's source code, modified it a bit, then I proceeded to remove the file from my project via pubspec. But now even after removing the package, when I re-installed the flutter package, edits I made previously in the package source code still remains. Please how do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the packages are cached in your system automatically, it is not enough to delete it from your pubspec.yaml file but you have to also manually delete it from your system.

If you are using Windows, the path to the cached packages from https://pub.dev/ is C:\Users{User}\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org.

Another option would be to run `flutter packages cache repair` if you are using flutter or `pub cache repair` if you are developing in dart.

I hope this helps!

Comment: "flutter packages cache repair" worked like a charm! Thanks so much, you saved my brain from exploding :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to repair the pub cache by running `pub cache repair` command or you can delete the package directly in the .pub_cache folder from your flutter install directory